# Install & Configure openssl on Jboss 4.2.1 on linux server

Tags: linux, openssl, jboss-4.2.x

I installed Jboss version 4.2.1.GA on a linux server, and now i need to install and configure openssl on this server, my problem is I searched the internet for the last 2 days and tried many solutions without being able to fix it.

any help or step by step guidance will be very very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below steps to compile OpenSSL Manually:

```
$ wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1a.tar.gz

$ tar -zxf openssl-1.0.1a.tar.gz

$ ./config --prefix=/usr zlib-dynamic --openssldir=/etc/ssl shared &&

$ make

$ make MANDIR=/usr/share/man install && install -v -d -m755 /usr/share/doc/openssl-1.0.1a && cp -v -r doc/{HOWTO,README,*.{txt,html,gif}} /usr/share/doc/openssl-1.0.1a
```

**Note:** If you have/had any specific problem then you should mentioned it in your initial question.

Regards.